# Nginx server crashing unexpectedly

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, mod-security

My nginx server in aws seems to crash with the following messages,

```
2019/01/14 12:37:25 [notice] 18928#0: ModSecurity-nginx v1.0.0

2019/01/14 12:37:25 [notice] 18928#0: signal process started

2019/01/14 12:37:25 [notice] 1415#0: signal 15 (SIGTERM) received from 18928, exiting

2019/01/14 12:37:25 [notice] 1424#0: exiting

2019/01/14 12:37:25 [notice] 1423#0: exiting

2019/01/14 12:37:25 [notice] 1425#0: exiting

2019/01/14 12:37:25 [notice] 1426#0: exiting

2019/01/14 12:37:25 [notice] 1425#0: exit

2019/01/14 12:37:25 [notice] 1415#0: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 1425

2019/01/14 12:37:25 [notice] 1415#0: worker process 1425 exited with code 0

2019/01/14 12:37:25 [notice] 1415#0: signal 29 (SIGIO) received

2019/01/14 12:37:25 [notice] 1424#0: exit

2019/01/14 12:37:25 [notice] 1415#0: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 1424

2019/01/14 12:37:25 [notice] 1415#0: worker process 1424 exited with code 0

2019/01/14 12:37:25 [notice] 1415#0: signal 29 (SIGIO) received

2019/01/14 12:37:25 [notice] 1426#0: exit

2019/01/14 12:37:25 [notice] 1415#0: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 1426

2019/01/14 12:37:25 [notice] 1415#0: worker process 1426 exited with code 0

2019/01/14 12:37:25 [notice] 1415#0: signal 29 (SIGIO) received

2019/01/14 12:37:25 [notice] 1423#0: exit

2019/01/14 12:37:25 [notice] 1415#0: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 1423

2019/01/14 12:37:25 [notice] 1415#0: worker process 1423 exited with code 0

2019/01/14 12:37:25 [notice] 1415#0: exit
```

I can't figure out why!

Comment: We need [more information](https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/weird-crash-over-night-with-nginx/185490/4) from you.

Comment: There is not enough information in the logs to find the cause of the problem. You can enable debug mode by changing the log level of the `error_log` directive to `debug`, for more details.